# Detect keyboard focus for INPUT fields

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have an app that is in world wide use for several years and in need of an update. It monitors keystrokes and then translates these into actions (opening file/folder/document etc) or substituting user defined text. It's not a key logger and please don't suggest otherwise.

Currently it uses `UIAccessibility` on Windows to detect password fields and then auto disable itself.

We are trying to implement an auto disable for browsers.

Using a webextension I have a couple of questions.

1) How can I detect when an `INPUT type='password'` gains keyboard focus?
2) How can I call a DLL or send a message to our app? (I have seen the maybe possible using `Native messaging` but not sure if this is the best or correct way.)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1) You need to add a content script to each and every page. In manifest.json, add this:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["contentscript-password.js"],
        "run_at": "document_start"
    }
],
```

When you have done that, you need to enumerate all inputs where type=password (getAttribute("type") == "password").

On every password input, you add an "change" event listener - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change

In that event listener, you send a message to the background script, which in turn can communicate with native messaging to some external piece of software that you wrote.

2) Yes, native messaging is the way to go. Since I have no experience in using it yet, you will have to find out how it works yourself. There is documentation about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_messaging

Comment: Great answer - thanks! I'm thinking the script could use a global `input.onfocus` and check for `type==password` - ok, need to dig into native messaging now ...